# gcd & lcm in a PID

Tags: divisibility, principal-ideal-domains

In a PID, $l={\rm lcm}(a,b)$ and $d=\gcd(a,b)$. Is it always true that the following product ideals are equal?
$$<d><l> = <a><b>$$

Thanks in advance

-- Mike

Comment: A PID is a UFD. Factor into primes, and express the lcm and gcd in terms of the factorizations.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, Thanks for the comment. However, I am not able to prove the equality. I could show (apparently I used precisely the same idea, you mentioned) that $<d><l>\subset <a><b>$. However could not figure out the other way inequality :(.

Comment: Just for us foreigners not used to those english acronyms: PID="[principal ideal domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_ideal_domain)" and UFD="[unique factorization domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A PID is a UFD. Let $$a=p_1^{r_1}p_2^{r_2}\cdots p_t^{r_t},\quad b=p_1^{s_1}p_2^{s_2}\cdots p_t^{s_t}$$ for primes $p_1,p_2,\dots,p_t$. Then $$\ell={\rm lcm}(a,b)=\prod p_j^{\max(r_j,s_j)},\quad d=\gcd(a,b)=\prod p_j^{\min(r_j,s_j)}$$ so $$\ell d=\prod p_j^{\max(r_j,s_j)+\min(r_j,s_j)}=\prod p_j^{r_j+s_j}=ab$$